# Iteratively write to the same process substitution file on MacOs

Tags: bash, process-substitution

The following bash-fu code works fine on Linux but breaks on MacOS:

```
files="foo bar"

echo PROG 1
for file in $files
do
  echo $file | tee -a tempfile.txt
done

sort -u tempfile.txt

echo PROG 2
function trick {
  for file in $files
  do
    echo $file | tee -a $1
  done
}

trick >(sort -u)
```

The error is:

```
PROG 1
foo
bar
bar
foo
PROG 2
tee: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor
foo
tee: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor
bar
```

On Linux `PROG 2` writes the same lines as `PROG 1` without errors. On MacOS it seems that the pipe handle is either closed or not inherited.

The above is the minimized sample to reproduce the problem. In reality I process both tie output and redirected handle heavily. Something in the spirit of

```
function trick {
  for file in $files
  do
     echo $file | tee -a $1 | grep -Eo "^.."
  done
}

trick >(sort -u | sed 's|o|x|g')
```

The code doesn't work in Bash 4.1, but works in Bash 4.4 in multiple distros (Arch, Ubuntu and Debian)

Comment: Have you heard of handle inheritance?

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Didn't think it through fully, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS comes with a very old version of `bash`. That bug (that the file descriptor for that process substitution is closed before calling `tee` in that context)¹ was fixed in newer versions. You'd get the same problem on Linux (with a different error message as `/dev/fd/x` is implemented differently there) with bash 3.2 there.

Here, you could use `zsh` or `ksh93` instead. It's a good idea to avoid `bash` here anyway as [it doesn't wait for processes in process substitutions](/a/403788) (zsh waits for them, ksh93 can be told to `wait` for them).

Note that even with the latest (4.4.12 as of writing) version, `bash` still has a few bugs here like:

```
$ bash -c 'eval cat <(echo test)'
test # OK but:
$ bash -c 'eval "echo foo;cat" <(echo test)'
foo
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
$ bash -c 'eval f=<(echo test) "; cat \$f"'
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

and some still triggered by pipes like:

```
$ cat file
echo "$1"
cat "$1"
$ bash -c 'source ./file <(echo test)'
/dev/fd/63
test  # OK but:
$ cat file2
echo "$1" | wc -c
cat "$1"
$ bash -c 'source ./file2 <(echo test)'
11
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

---

¹ bash closes that file descriptor as soon as a there is a pipeline. A shorter reproducer:

```
$ bash -c 'f() { :; cat "$1"; }; f <(echo OK)'
OK
$ bash -c 'f() { :|:; cat "$1"; }; f <(echo test)'
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```